# LCM self test failed, Check your routing tables and firewall settings

Tags: ubuntu, bazel, drake

I have ubuntu 20.04, I install drake and try run example.
When I try run `bazel-bin/tools/drake_visualizer & bazel-bin/examples/multibody/inclined_plane_with_body/inclined_plane_with_body` I have got error:

```
[1] 121628
LCM self test failed!!
Check your routing tables and firewall settings
LCM self test failed!!
Check your routing tables and firewall settings
*** buffer overflow detected ***: terminated
LCM self test failed!!
Check your routing tables and firewall settings
[1]+  Aborted                 (core dumped) bazel-bin/tools/drake_visualizer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something with LCM's networking configuration isn't working. For example, if there is no lo (loopback) device, or it's disabled, or configured oddly.

See https://lcm-proj.github.io/multicast_setup.html for some tips.

Comment: Thank you, this commands help me `sudo ifconfig lo multicast & sudo route add -net 224.0.0.0 netmask 240.0.0.0 dev lo `

Comment: This command also solved the issue for me.